# Can I retrieve an Email Alert via the Ant Migration Tool?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, ant, migration-tool, mdapi

I wanted to retrieve an Email Alert via the Ant Migration Tool. However, I could not find it in a [Metadata Types Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm). I suppose it's hidden under some other name like many other SF Metadata Types - I just don't know which.

To make things more precise - pic related:

[image]

Comment: Look for WorkflowAlert

Follow this link for more info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm

Comment: @Raj you should consider fleshing that idea out (i.e. can't find a metadata type, go up a level or two and try to follow it down) and turning it into an answer.

Comment: @Raj Agree with Derek, it worked. Funny thing is that I could define WorkflowAlert in a package.xml (it's not listed on a mentioned page of MD API docs).

Comment: @DerekF and notmyf4ulty
 Turning it to an answer, may be some up votes from you guys :). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve it with "workflowAlert" metadatatype. You can find more info at this URL here [Workflow Metadata Ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm), you might want to scroll through to the section "WorkflowAlert" to see field references associated to it.

[image: WorkflowAlert]

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve WorkflowAlert with the Metadata API you need to make sure to include the object name before the alert name i.e Case.My_Alert or Account.Hello_World